# How partiton pruning works on integer column in snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake with around 1000 columns, i have an id column which is of integer type

when i run query like

`select * from table where id=12`
it is scanning all the micro-paritions .I am expecting that snowflake will maintain metadata of min/max of id column and based on that it should scan only one partition rather than all the partition.

In this doc https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html its mentioned that they maintain min/max , disticnt value of  columns in each micro-partition.

How can i take advantage of partititon pruning in this scenario?Currently even for unique id snowflake is scanning all the partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more complicated than that unfortunately. Snowflake would only scan a single partition if your table was perfectly **clustered** by your `id` column, which it probably isn't, nor should it be. Snowflake is a data warehouse and isn't ideal for single-row lookups.

You could always cluster your table by your `id` column but you usually don't want to do this in a data warehouse. I would recommend reading [this document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) to understand how table clustering works.

Comment: Each values in `id` column is unqiue so it  does not make sense to make it as cluster key beacuse of high cardinality. 
But just to undesrtand if i make it as cluster key snoflake will maintain the metadata and will scan only one partition?
In this doc https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html , it is mentioned that they maintain distinct and min/max value for each column to enable partition pruning.

Comment: It does make sense if it is a static table and you're always doing ID lookups and not much else. If the table isn't static and you're always loading data into it with unknown IDs each time then there isn't much else you can do.

Comment: Snowflake does maintain a min/max values in the metadata layer for each column and micro partition, it's not something you enable or disable. But in your example, it's likely that you will have the same ID in many micro partitions because your table probably isn't clustered by ID so Snowflake needs to search them all.

Comment: Agree, in my case its a id(which is unique) so it is available in only one partition but snowflake is scanning all the partition ,pruning is not happening at all.

Comment: Right. You would need to run clustering on the table so that all your IDs that are close to each other belong to the same micro partition. Doing this would impact other types of queries on different columns though. Also, if you load more data into the table those new IDs would need to be reclustered too.

Comment: Thanks make sense, Currently it might be the case range of id column min/max in each partiton is large and my id is lying in between . Snowflake is trying to find my id in each partition  .Clustering will help in this case.

Comment: Just curious , if id column will be fo string type what will be the behaviour with clustering in place?